# Cocos2D - Running an action on a label

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, label, action

Im trying to generate an action for a label, which is a property of a sprite.

This is what Im trying but the labels aren't moving and I can't pinpoint what could be the cause for them not to move..

```
    - (void) spriteLabelMoveFinished:(id)sender
    {
CCLOG(@"AnimateLabel Move Finished");
Sprites *sprite = (Sprites *)sender;

CCLOG(@"LabelFinalPosition: %f,%f",sprite.spriteLabel.position.x,sprite.spriteLabel.position.y);
[self animateSpriteLabel:sprite.spriteLabel];

    }


    -(void)animateSpriteLabel:(Sprites *)sprite
    {
CCLOG(@"We're animating the SpriteLabel");

CCLabelTTF *spriteLabel = nil;

spriteLabel = sprite.spriteLabel;


int actualDuration = spriteLabelSpeed; // Another Property, inside the .m

// Create the actions

CCLOG(@"AnimatingLabel LabelPosition: %f,%f",spriteLabel.position.x,spriteLabel.position.y);

id actionMove = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:actualDuration
                                    position:ccpMult(ccpNormalize(ccpSub(_player.position,spriteLabel.position)), 10)];

id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(spriteLabelMoveFinished:)];
[sprite runAction:
 [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

    }
```

The label just appears and doesn't move....
Thanks for your help and your time, have a good one!

Comment: This code isn`t in a loop? Sprite calling spriteLabelMoveFinished, and calling animateSpriteLabel over and over again?

Comment: @MauricioTollin Yes, I create the sprite add it on the screen(the label is a property on sprite.h) and just as its created I call the function animateSpriteLabel: as well as animateSprite: (which is a similar function but instead of moving the Label , moves the sprite and that one works fine)

Answer (score 0):

You are running action on Sprite object, not on the spriteLabel.
Try to change:

```
[sprite runAction:
    [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
```

to

```
[spriteLabel runAction:
    [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
```

Comment: I tried this, but spriteLabel is a CCLabelTTF which is part of sprite
(sprite.spriteLabel) and animateSpriteLabel is expecting type Sprites, not CCLabelTTF so I get this error:
[CCLabelTTF spriteLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8442310

Comment: You may not have given me an exact answer but you sure did pinpoint to the right direction, All i did was change what the function was expecting to CCLabelTTF, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
[self animateSpriteLabel:sprite.spriteLabel];
```

should read:

```
[self animateSpriteLabel:sprite];
```

This I think would have the result you're after. I'm a little surprised you didn't have a compiler warning/error.